How to compare two Guid List?
I have a Model with a Guid list.
public class DetailModel 
{
       
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ProductResource), Name = "ProductCode")]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ProductResource), Name = "RealPrice")]
    public decimal RealPrice { get; set; }

    
    public float ExistCount { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Guid> Items { get; set; }

}

I have a list of Guid , I want to compare this list with Items list in Model.
foreach (var DetailModel in details)
 {
   var values = DetailModel.Items.ToList();
   var selected = list of guid;

   var s = values.Equals(selected);
 }

Equals is false always.
How to compare two list?

What makes the two lists equal (or not equal). If two lists are equal, are the items in the lists in the same order? Whatever you do, you will likely loop over the two lists comparing the individual items. If you are going to do this often, you may want to create an implementation of IEqualityComparer<IList<Guid>>

You can sort both the list first, and then can use SequenceEqual() method present in System.Linq
values.Sort();
selected.Sort();

bool areEqual = values.SequenceEqual(selected);

